# Keep react front end from disconnecting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

In a client server single-page application using `Node.js`, `React`, `express` and `socket.io`, the user disconnects if there is no client side activity [I think. It might be on the server `socket.io` end that the disconnect is initiated.]

How can I tell `React` to send "pings" to the server so that it doesn't disconnect ever - even without user activity on the browser? Is there a technique for this?

I have seen this, but this technique seems to be on the server end. Besides, I don't want the timeout to occur ever unless the user closes the web page.

```
io.connect(SERVER_IP, {'forceNew': true});
```

This is app.js on the client side.

```
var WatchStock = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {symbol: ""};
    },
    watchStock: function() {
        this.props.watchStockHandler(this.state.symbol);
        this.setState({symbol: ''});
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({symbol: event.target.value});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <p>Available stocks: IBM, INTC</p>  
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: i think it's no good idea to solve from react, but u can within componentDidMount start timer with => io.connect(SERVER_IP, {'forceNew': true}); (in componentWillUnmount clear timer ofc)

Comment: Where would you solve it from if it is the client that is disconnecting?

Comment: socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.connect(callback);
});